# VB.NET DataGridview Filtering runs automatically

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filtering

Almost done with this project, but yet another bug. When my form loads, I select my filter criteria with check boxes and press a "populate" button to fill the DGV. The user is to fill in missing pieces of data in a few columns. The filter ONLY populates data that needs data filled in.

My issue...If you fill in the missing data for the row and click onto the next row, the previous row is filtered and disappears. It was never saved, so when I re-populate, it returns, but empty.

I do not want the filter to re-run automatically. I want all the data to stay until the user is done and saves. Then when the "populate" button is clicked again, the rows that were filled completely are not populated. 
It seems like it should be a simple property, but I have not been able to find a simple solution.

Thank you in advance. 
I will attached my code for reference.

```
        Private Sub DataEntry3_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing

    'Closes all DataSets and Bindings 
    ProductionDownTimeDataSet1.Dispose()
    DownTimeCodesDataSet.Dispose()

    ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Dispose()
    DTCodeDataBindingSource.Dispose()

    'Form Is Closing-Closes all other forms
    Selection.Close()
    SelectDataByLineForm.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub xP3PopulateBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles xP3PopulateBtn.Click


    Delay(1)
    'Active Filters
    Try
        Dim strFilterP3 As String = String.Empty
        'CheckBox Filtering code=Search for Incomplete Cells Line 2 Only 
        If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = True And
        xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = False And
        xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = False Then
            strFilterP3 = ("(DTReasonBadgeNo Is Null Or DTEventReason Is Null Or DTReasonDateTime Is Null)")
            strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" And [LineID]= '3'")
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"
        End If

        'CheckBox Filtering code=Search for Incomplete Cells on first and second shift only Lines 1N and 1S Only 
        If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = True And
        xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = True And
        xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = True Then
            strFilterP3 = ("(DTReasonBadgeNo Is Null Or DTEventReason Is Null Or DTReasonDateTime Is Null) And (Shift = 1 Or Shift = 2)")
            strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" And [LineID]= '3'")
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"
        End If

        'CheckBox Filtering code=Search for Incomplete Cells on first shift only Line 2 Only 
        If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = True And
   xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = True And
   xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = False Then
            strFilterP3 = ("(DTReasonBadgeNo Is Null Or DTEventReason Is Null Or DTReasonDateTime Is Null) and Shift = 1")
            strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" and [LineID]= '3'")
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"
        End If

        'CheckBox Filtering code=Search for Incomplete Cells on second shift only Line 2 Only 
        If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = True And
   xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = False And
   xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = True Then
            strFilterP3 = ("(DTReasonBadgeNo Is Null Or DTEventReason Is Null Or DTReasonDateTime Is Null) and Shift = 2")
            strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" and [LineID]= '3'")
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"
        End If

        'CheckBox Filtering Code=Incomplete and Complete Cells on First Shift Only Line 2 Only 
        If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = False And
   xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = True And
   xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = False Then
            strFilterP3 = "Shift = 1"
            strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" and [LineID]= '3'")
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"

        End If

        'CheckBox Filtering Code=Incomplete And Complete Cells on Second Shift Only Line 2 Only 
        If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = False And
    xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = False And
    xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = True Then
            strFilterP3 = "Shift = 2"
            strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" and [LineID]= '3'")
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"
        End If


        'CheckBox Filtering Code=S how All Line 2 Only 
        If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = False And
  xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = False And
  xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = False Then
            strFilterP3 = "1 = 1"
            strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" and [LineID]= '3'")
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"

        End If

        'CheckBox Filter Code Show all Data from First and Second Shift Line 2 Only  
        If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = False And
            xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = True And
            xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = True Then
            strFilterP3 = ("(Shift = 1 Or  Shift = 2)")
            strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" And [LineID]= '3'")
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"
        End If

        'This line of code loads data into the 'ProductionDownTimeDataSet.ProductionDownTimeTable' table.

        Me.ProductionDownTimeTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProductionDownTimeDataSet1.ProductionDownTimeTable)



    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub xP3GotoSelectionScreenButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles xP3GotoSelectionScreenButton.Click
    'Opens the Production Line Selection Form 
    Selection.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub xP3DETimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles xP3DETimer.Tick
    'Read the Login status from the PLC and Display the User Logged In as the text
    Dim L3Login As String
    L3Login = EthernetIPforSLCMicroCom1.Read("ST20:0")
    xP3DELoginLabel.Text = L3Login

    'Disables changing the filter unless engineering is logged in
    If L3Login = "Engineering" Then
        xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Visible = True
    Else
        xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Visible = False

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ProductionDownTimeTableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProductionDownTimeTableBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    'DataGridView-Binding Navigtor Save Button 
    Try
        Me.Validate()
        Me.ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ProductionDownTimeDataSet1)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ProductionDownTimeTableDataGridView_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles ProductionDownTimeTableDataGridView.DataBindingComplete
    'After Binding the DataSource to the DatgridView, This fills the Combobox. Previous to waiting for this event, I had issues with
    '"System.ArgumentException:DatagridViewComboBoxCell value not valid" errors at population. 
    Me.DTCodeDataTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DownTimeCodesDataSet.DTCodeData)

    'Enables the time/date stamp when a cell is changed in the DataGridView 
    allDoneLoading = True

End Sub


Dim allDoneLoading As Boolean = False
Dim DateTimeColumnIndex As Integer = 1

Private Sub ProductionDownTimeTableDataGridView_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles ProductionDownTimeTableDataGridView.CellValueChanged

    Try
        'AllDoneLoading keeps the code from triggering during the loading of the Datagridview and erroring 

        If allDoneLoading = True Then

            If (e.ColumnIndex <> DateTimeColumnIndex) Then
                For z As Integer = 0 To ProductionDownTimeTableDataGridView.ColumnCount - 1
                    If ProductionDownTimeTableDataGridView.Item(z, e.RowIndex).Value Is Nothing Then
                        Return
                    End If
                    ProductionDownTimeTableDataGridView.Item(10, e.RowIndex).Value = DateTime.Now
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: It disappears because the row no longer fits the filter criteria (it is not "rerunning").  Even if you cant see it, it is there though.  you need to update to save to the database.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Unfortunately, I do not want it to "disappear" from the users view util the user saves. Maybe I am "missing" what you are telling me.

Comment: Plutonix, In addition to your comment, I did find an article on the MSDN site that explains that this doesn't seem possible for me.

Comment: It is possible, just not the way you are doing it.  If you dont allow incomplete data to be saved then the ID for those rows should be null, 0 or <0 depending on how you are doing it.  If you filter on *that* it is the same thing.  You could also add an Incomplete column to the datatable which is set to True for those rows and filter on that.